# Running a task of Visual Studio Code from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've a simple project in visual studio code with some defined tasks in `tasks.json`. Let's say the task are labeled with `foo` and `bar`.

Inside of visual studio code I can run CTRL+B and select the wanted task.

But - How can I run the task `foo` from a command line outside of Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Looking for something like: `code /path/to/my/project --run-task foo`

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: I opened [an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112594) in vscode's github repo for this

Comment: Please upvote that issue. If it doesn't get 20 upvotes in the next 60 days vscode will delete it.

Comment: Looks like it was closed unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [python tool](https://github.com/cmccandless/vstask) that runs the vscode tasks. The last commit was in 2018, but it still might work as it seems that the tasks were last changed in [vscode 1.13](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks), released in [2017](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13).

edit:
It works but `setup.py:8` needs to be edited to build the wheel on windows, as it tries to run a shell script. My edit was to change the line to `log = subprocess.check_output('sh bin/changelog')` as I have `sh` installed.

Comment: vstask doesn't work with tasks version 2.

Comment: @THansda vstask has been updated to support tasks version 2

Comment: @ompadu I also patched the shell reference bug you noted, thanks for that